# How to use unique AndroidSDK resources for each Android Project in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

I would like to make some core changes within the SDK; however, as I understand, all my projects are compiled from the same AndroidSDK in a folder on my system and I don't want to make these changes for all of my projects.

Where in Eclipse can I change where a specific project sources its SDK from?

If I'm being a little confusing, please let me know!

Answer (score 0):

You can not change SDK preferences For each and every project in Eclipse.Once if you set the android SDK it will set for all the projects corresponding to that eclipse work space.

For this you have to change your custom SDK into android library and add it to your corresponding projects.